# Using namespace in multiple VCL modules

Tags: c++, linker, namespaces, c++builder

I'd like to use a certain `namespace` along with its functions to be used in several forms to have sort of shared functions. However, I am having linker problem.

Here is what I did - I created a new unit and inside of it I wrote in header file:

```c++
#ifndef MyHeaderH
#define MyHeaderH

namespace MyHeader
    {
    enum { SOMETHING1, SOMETHING2 };
    void SomeFunction(int Param);
    }

#endif
```

Of course, the actual function is defined in **cpp** file, the above is just from **h** file.

And the **cpp** file is as follows:

```c++
#pragma hdrstop
#include "MyHeader.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)

void SomeFunction(int Param)
{
//some code here
}
```

So in my main form `Form1` I include the above in **hpp** file of `Form1`

```c++
MyHeader::SomeFunction(0);
```

This all compiles fine but the linker reports unresolved external. So obviously it doesn't see the namespace and function. How do I fix that?

As an additional question - if I use such function set in several forms, it should be all compiled just once and reused right (it won't have several copies of same functions I guess?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to put the function definition in the namespace.

It's either done like you do in the header file, but with a function body:

```
namespace MyHeader
{
    void SomeFunction(int Param)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or using the scope operator `::`:

```
void MyHeader::SomeFunction(int Param)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was some stupid error like that. Included `MyHeader::` before function implementation in **cpp** file and now it compiles! What about that other question - is this function now compiled only once in entire program?

Comment: @Coder12345 Yes, as there's only one *definition* then there will be only one copy of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The actual function is defined in the cpp file in a way that it does not implement the interface declared in the header file.

Implement

```
namespace MyHeader
{
    void SomeFunction(int Param) { /* Your implementation goes here. */ }
}
```

in the cpp file.